# Sampling a new random ValidationSet at each epoch during NetTrain

Tags: neural-networks

My understanding is that the [NetTrain](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetTrain.html) option `ValidationSet ->Scaled[0.2]` setting will randomly sample 20% of the training data at the beginning of the fitting process, and use that selection throughout the process to calculate the validation set metric.  (Specifically, the documentation states that it will "reserve a specified fraction of the training set for validation"; this is also implied in the [neural networks regularization methods document](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksRegularization.html#825325933))

**How would you generate a new, randomly sampled validation set at each epoch?** (leaving aside whether this is a good practice or not...I'm trying to reproduce a paper which claims to use a randomly sampled 80% of the training data at each epoch for SGD and the other 20% for validation, resampled at each epoch)

The closest I can figure out is to `RandomSample` the pool of data for each of the processes.  This doesn't quite achieve the desired goal (there is a non-zero chance of the same example appearing in both the training and validation set during the same epoch)

```mathematica
example = (# -> Sin[#]) & /@ RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, 100]; (*example data*)

nn = NetChain[{LinearLayer[10], Ramp, LinearLayer[{}]}] (* example network*)

(*use Unevaluated so that new samples occur at each pass through the training process*)
result = NetTrain[
  nn, Unevaluated[RandomSample[example, 80]], All,
  ValidationSet -> Unevaluated[RandomSample[example, 20]]
 ]
```

Comment: In your code you are clobbering `example` which was formerly training data with a network. I think you meant to do `nn = NetTrain[nn, ...]`.

Comment: You're right, flinty.  Editing to clarify

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be very efficient because it will keep jumping in and out of the training, but it's possible to partially train a net and then continue the training with new data like this `nn = NetTrain[nn, ...]`. Here I do 10 rounds of training, then reshuffle and continue:

```
example = (# -> Sin[#]) & /@ RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, 100];
nn = NetChain[{LinearLayer[10, "Input" -> "Real"], Ramp, LinearLayer[{}]}] 

nn = NetInitialize[nn];
Do[
 {training, validation} = 
  ResourceFunction["TrainTestSplit"][example, 
   "TestSetSize" -> Scaled[.2]];
 nn = NetTrain[nn, training, ValidationSet -> validation, 
   MaxTrainingRounds -> 10]
 , 500]
```

You could set `MaxTrainingRounds` to 1 but it would be very slow to get to 500 rounds.